# PyQt5 A QA about menubar visibility by mouseover

Tags: python, pyqt5

Im using PyQT5 and Python Version is 3.78.

I got a request than when I mouse over the button and display menubar.I made that code and it works.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QInputDialog, QLineEdit)

from app.strategy.menu_strategy import MenuStrategy


class DrawMenuWnd(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        super(DrawMenuWnd, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ctrl = None    # source from wnd hook event
        # self.menu_stg_obj = MenuStrategy(state_mq)  # stop operation when input sth..
        # set title
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        # set win size and attrs
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Tool | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.initial_ui()

    def initial_ui(self):
        self.menubar = self.menuBar()
        self.menubar.setFont(QFont('微软雅黑'))
        self.coin = QIcon(r'./arrow.jpeg')
        # root menu
        self.root_menu = self.menubar.addMenu(self.coin, "")
        # mouse child menu
        self.left_single = QAction("left click", self)
        self.left_double_single = QAction("left double click", self)
        self.right_single = QAction("right click", self)
        self.root_menu.addAction(self.left_single)
        self.root_menu.addAction(self.left_double_single)
        self.root_menu.addAction(self.right_single)
        # seperator
        self.root_menu.addSeparator()
        # keyboard child menu
        self.input = QAction("keyboard input", self)
        self.root_menu.addAction(self.input)
        # connect function
        # self.left_single.triggered.connect(self.menu_stg_obj.click)
        # self.left_double_single.triggered.connect(self.menu_stg_obj.double_click)
        # self.right_single.triggered.connect(self.menu_stg_obj.right_click)
        # self.input.triggered.connect(self.menu_stg_obj.keyboard_input)
        # set event filter
        self.menubar.installEventFilter(self)

    @classmethod
    def initial_menu(cls, title):
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = DrawMenuWnd(title)
        window.show()
        app.exec_()

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        try:
            if event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
                print("Mouse is over the label")
                if self.root_menu.isHidden():
                    self.root_menu.show()
                # print('program stop is', self.stop)
                return True
            elif event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
                print("Mouse is not over the label")
                self.root_menu.hide()
                # print('program stop is', self.stop)
            return False
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DrawMenuWnd("")
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Now I got a question that when I mouse away from button, the menubar should disappear but now not.
So now I wanna let the menubar disappear after my mouse away from the button, I try to hide the menubar in using function `hide()` but it not works

Anybody help?

thanks

Comment: I think you are loosing the focus when the menu is popping out. so you don't enter in the QEvent.Leave condition.

Comment: Yes, you right. As ur conclusion, I test it many times and find that my func cant trigger QEvent.Leave condition, because the menu list is covering the button, and now I trying to slove it for this situation.  @ymmx

Comment: you should probable rewrite the Qmenu class to include a method that close the menu when the mouse leave the menu itself. You also need to be careful if you hide the menu just when leaving the icon you probably won't be able to select anything in that menu.

Comment: Thanks for ur great suggestion, I will try it and take my answer back  @ymmx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I meant is something like that :

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QInputDialog, QLineEdit,QMenu)




class MyQMenu(QMenu):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QMenu.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def leaveEvent(self, QEvent):
        # here the code for mouse leave
        self.close()
        print('Leave')



class DrawMenuWnd(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        super(DrawMenuWnd, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ctrl = None    # source from wnd hook event
        # self.menu_stg_obj = MenuStrategy(state_mq)  # stop operation when input sth..
        # set title
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        # set win size and attrs
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Tool | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.initial_ui()

    def initial_ui(self):
        self.menubar = self.menuBar()
        self.menubar.setFont(QFont('微软雅黑'))
        self.coin = QIcon(r'./arrow.jpeg')
        # root menu
        self.root_menu = MyQMenu( "")
        self.root_menu.setIcon(self.coin)
        self.menubar.addMenu(self.root_menu)
        # mouse child menu
        self.left_single = QAction("left click", self)
        self.left_double_single = QAction("left double click", self)
        self.right_single = QAction("right click", self)
        self.root_menu.addAction(self.left_single)
        self.root_menu.addAction(self.left_double_single)
        self.root_menu.addAction(self.right_single)
        # seperator
        self.root_menu.addSeparator()
        # keyboard child menu
        self.input = QAction("keyboard input", self)
        self.root_menu.addAction(self.input)
        # connect function
        # self.left_single.triggered.connect(self.menu_stg_obj.click)
        # self.left_double_single.triggered.connect(self.menu_stg_obj.double_click)
        # self.right_single.triggered.connect(self.menu_stg_obj.right_click)
        # self.input.triggered.connect(self.menu_stg_obj.keyboard_input)
        # set event filter
        self.menubar.installEventFilter(self)

    @classmethod
    def initial_menu(cls, title):
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = DrawMenuWnd(title)
        window.show()
        app.exec_()

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        try:
            if event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
                print("Mouse is over the label")
                if self.root_menu.isHidden():
                    self.root_menu.show()
                # print('program stop is', self.stop)
                return True
            elif event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
                print("Mouse is not over the label")
                self.root_menu.hide()
                # print('program stop is', self.stop)
            return False
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DrawMenuWnd("")
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Thats what I wanna do, appreciation for you